# The usage of "avrai voglia" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses

> *Guarda il video e avrai voglia di fare un ricco aperitivo nel centro storico di qualche città italiana.*

I don't understand why we use **avere** (indicativo futuro) + **volere** (congiuntivo presente) instead of simply **vorrai** (indicativo futuro) or **vorresti** (condizionale).

Answer (score 5):

"Voglia" in "avere voglia" is a noun, not a verb in the congiuntivo.

"Avere voglia (di fare qc)" can be literally translated as "To have the desire (to do sth.)".

The difference to "volere" is similar to the difference between

"I feel like dancing" and "I want to dance" (volere)

I hope a native speaker can confirm this.

Comment: A fine explanation indeed.